# Confusion while trying to access and array inside of an array.

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest, fetch-api

For example, I'm using the fetch api to grab data from the NY times api and. Inside of the response, there is an object named "Multimedia" that has images in it. I've created a template literal to grab the necessary data but can't seem to get any of the images to pull in. [DEMO ON CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Brushel/pen/wXeXVg) Here is my code:

```js
const div = document.getElementById('article'),
      url = "https://api.nytimes.com/svc/topstories/v2/home.json?api-key=fd168d666e644fe29bbb534d757b374e";

fetch(url)
.then((response) => {return response.json(); })
.then(data => {  
  
  let article = data.results;
  console.log(article);

  return article.map(user => {
    let output = '<div class="container">';
    article.forEach(user => {
      output += `
      <article>
        <img src="${user.multimedia.url}">
        <h2>${user.title}</h2>
        <span class="author"><b>Author:</b> ${user.byline} | <b>Category: </b>${user.section}</span>
        <p>${user.abstract}</p>
        <a class="btn" href="${user.url}" target="_blank">View Article</a>
      </article>
    `
    });
    document.getElementById('article').innerHTML = output;
  })
})
.catch( error => { console.log(error); })
```

```html
%body
  #article
```

I've tried to access the images with user.multimedia.url but I can't seem to pull in the images. Any help or explanation as to why I can't get this t work would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It looks like user.multimedia is an array of objects, not just a single value. You'll either need to iterate through the array or select the item you want by index. Here's a quick example using the first image in the array - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKKGBy?editors=1010

Comment: it also seems that variable `user` is being used in forEach along with Map, so try changing variable name.

Comment: @BrettGregson thank you so much that worked perfectly!

Comment: Thanks @ThomasBrushel. I posted it as an answer as well for anyone who ends up on this post in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like user.multimedia is an array of objects, not just a single value. You'll either need to iterate through the array or select the item you want by index:

```
user.multimedia[0].url
```

[Here's a quick example using the first image in the array](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qKKGBy?editors=1010)

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over `user.multimedia` like this

```
var imgs = "";
    article.map(user => {
      user.multimedia.map(i=>{
       imgs += "<img src="+i.url+">"
      })
```

and in `output` put `${imgs}` where you want the images. There are several images with different sizes, so you should pick one of them I think.